# Heroku builds failing on nodejs app, how do I resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm  getting strange and hard to trace errors, I was able to push fine for months, and now all my builds are failing and I don't know why, can anyone help?

I've checked and removed any node_modules from the git repo,
set the node version.

I don't even know where to start debugging, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! my build and my app runs locally fine..

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.13.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.12.0
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > iconv@2.3.2 install /tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/node_modules/iconv
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/node_modules/iconv/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/iconv/src/binding.o
remote:        In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cassert:44:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:26,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:55,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In destructor ‘virtual Nan::ObjectWrap::~ObjectWrap()’:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’
remote:             assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
remote:                                 ^
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In static member function ‘static void Nan::ObjectWrap::WeakCallback(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:127:26: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’
remote:             assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
remote:                                  ^
remote:        ../src/binding.cc: In static member function ‘static void {anonymous}::Iconv::Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’:
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:70:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()’
remote:                      Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(Make)->GetFunction());
remote:                                                                    ^
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5995:46: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction(v8::Local<v8::Context>)
remote:           V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
remote:                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5995:46: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:72:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()’
remote:                      Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(Convert)->GetFunction());
remote:                                                                       ^
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5995:46: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction(v8::Local<v8::Context>)
remote:           V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
remote:                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5995:46: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:74:77: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             obj->Set(Nan::New<String>(#err).ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(err))
remote:                                                                                     ^
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:75:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPORT_ERRNO’
remote:             EXPORT_ERRNO(EINVAL);
remote:             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3403:22: note: declared here
remote:                         bool Set(Local<Value> key, Local<Value> value));
remote:                              ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
remote:           declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
remote:           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:74:77: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             obj->Set(Nan::New<String>(#err).ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(err))
remote:                                                                                     ^
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:76:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPORT_ERRNO’
remote:             EXPORT_ERRNO(EILSEQ);
remote:             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3403:22: note: declared here
remote:                         bool Set(Local<Value> key, Local<Value> value));
remote:                              ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
remote:           declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
remote:           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:74:77: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             obj->Set(Nan::New<String>(#err).ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(err))
remote:                                                                                     ^
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:77:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPORT_ERRNO’
remote:             EXPORT_ERRNO(E2BIG);
remote:             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3403:22: note: declared here
remote:                         bool Set(Local<Value> key, Local<Value> value));
remote:                              ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
remote:           declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
remote:           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/binding.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Iconv::Make(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:91:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::ObjectTemplate::NewInstance()’
remote:                 Nan::New<ObjectTemplate>(object_template)->NewInstance();
remote:                                                                        ^
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:6292:44: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::ObjectTemplate::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>)
remote:           V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> NewInstance(Local<Context> context);
remote:                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:6292:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
remote:        ../src/binding.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Iconv::Convert(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:126:72: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Set(uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             rc->Set(0, Nan::New<Integer>(static_cast<uint32_t>(input_consumed)));
remote:                                                                                ^
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3412:22: note: declared here
remote:                         bool Set(uint32_t index, Local<Value> value));
remote:                              ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
remote:           declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
remote:           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/binding.cc:127:73: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Set(uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             rc->Set(1, Nan::New<Integer>(static_cast<uint32_t>(output_consumed)));
remote:                                                                                 ^
remote:        In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
remote:                         from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
remote:                         from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
remote:                         from ../src/binding.cc:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3412:22: note: declared here
remote:                         bool Set(uint32_t index, Local<Value> value));
remote:                              ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
remote:           declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
remote:           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        iconv.target.mk:113: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/iconv/src/binding.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/iconv/src/binding.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/node_modules/iconv/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_2fae94cddee9e19c317397e0a70bc2ff/node_modules/iconv
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! iconv@2.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.3.2 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.B2Pnc/_logs/2019-10-28T04_57_07_565Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to nameless-reef-31035.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/nameless-reef-31035.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: experiencing the same issue, did you get resolved?

Comment: asked support and they suggested to downgrade to Node v10 which worked for me

Comment: @MarioPérez yes, Heroku updated Node, I had not specified my node version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this issue is to specify a Node version.